# ReactNative Crashlytics doesn't send logs when application crash or log

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have a React Native application i installed firebase successfly

```
  "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.8",
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.6",
  "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.4.11",
```

i can see on dashboard analytics on firebase that i have One user Active, i do some crash to simulate crashes, but i can't see them on firebase, i have a loader that says add sdk firebase ....

[image]

[image]

When i see on log console xcode i can see there is problem with crashlytics :

[Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Failed to download settings Error Domain=FIRCLSNetworkError Code=-6 "(null)" UserInfo={retryLimit=1, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/gmp/1:359190975801:ios:9ed89ac2d5d316ebe184e8/settings?build_version=4&display_version=2.009&instance=107518e136276e412097823086820b54535a54f6&source=1}
2020-10-27 10:46:25.558428+0100 MYAPPLI****[4103:1348887] Task <30DF78EC-4FD2-41EF-A978-33989A7C7CFB>.<2> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "Request timed out earlier than tunneling config was received." UserInfo={_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <30DF78EC-4FD2-41EF-A978-33989A7C7CFB>.<2>"
), NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request timed out earlier than tunneling config was received., _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <30DF78EC-4FD2-41EF-A978-33989A7C7CFB>.<2>}

I also tried to add log on the reactnative code :

```
 import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';
 
 
  crashlytics().log('Updating user count.');
```

But nothing showed on crashlytics

any help will be appreciated

-------------------------------Edit---------------------------------------
when i add ${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run to build phase run script i don't get anymore error on log console xcode, but still can't see any log on crashlytics console

Comment: Please make sure to disconnect the simulator from the Xcode debugger to see crashes.

Comment: Still the same problem ... i will wait several minutes to see if it appears

Comment: It's really strange :( doesn't work

Comment: Alright. One last thing you can try is, test your crashes in release build.

Comment: i can't test caash on release build because it's not me whi sign the ipa, it's to client to do that